# $2^x\equiv 2017\pmod{3^{11}}$ and $2^x\equiv 2016\pmod{11^3}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, computer-assisted-proofs

> Find an integer $x$ such that $2^x\equiv 2017\pmod{3^{11}}$ and $2^x\equiv 2016\pmod{11^3}$

How can I solve this question?

Comment: Which contest is this? Please link to it so prospective responders can verify that it is not ongoing.

Comment: Just a local contest.

Comment: You haven't answered the question about whether it is still ongoing. We don't like to help people cheat in ongoing contests.

Comment: This is not ongoing contest. This finished a month ago. I am sorry, I have no more informations.

Comment: Isn't $11^3 \times 3^{11}$ an upper limit?

Answer (score 0):

First find $y$ such that $2^y\equiv 2017\pmod{3^{11}}$ and $z$ such that $2^z\equiv 2016 \pmod{11^3}$. (These are *discrete logarithm* problems, which are hard in general, but if you have computer support, a brute-force search is feasible with moduli as small as these).

Then you need to find $x$ such that
$$x\equiv y\pmod{\varphi(3^{11})} \qquad\text{and}\qquad x\equiv z\pmod{\varphi(11^3)}.$$
This is almost just an application of the *Chinese Remainder Theorem*, except that $\varphi(3^{11})$ and $\varphi(11^3)$ have a factor of $2$ in common -- so better hope that $x$ and $y$ are either both odd or both even, and you can then use the CRT with the three moduli $2$, $3^{10}$, and $5\cdot 11^2$.

Comment: I know this method, but the problem is, I am not sure that $y,z$ are both odd or both even.

Comment: @JieFan: I don't understand that. Once you have found $y$ and $z$ it ought to be very easy to see whether they are odd or even. Which values do you get for $y$ and $z$?